VueJS with TypeScript: Get the text content of a slot (to translate it)
I want to write a GoogleTranslate.vue component, that translates its contents to your mother language.
Here is my code
<template>

  <div>
  <slot></slot>
  //This is a tooltip from bootstrap
  <i class="ms-2 bi bi-globe" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" :title="translateText()"></i>
  </div>



</template>

<script lang="ts">

import { defineComponent } from "vue";


export default defineComponent({
  name: "VueGoogleTranslate",
  components: {
    
  },
  props: {
   
  },

  mounted() {
    
  },
  setup() {
    
  },

  methods: {
    translateText() {
         //Get the text content of slot and translate it with the google-translate-api
        let textToTranslate : string = this.$slots.default[0].text;
        return textToTranslate;
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
     
    };
  }
});
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>

I want to use the component somewhere else like this:
<GoogleTranslate>
Ce test est en français et devrait être traduit en anglais.
</GoogleTranslate>

The command
npm run build

gives me now the error
src/components/atoms/GoogleTranslate.vue:35:40 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'Slot<any>'.
  Property '0' does not exist on type 'Slot<any>'.

35         let textToTranslate : string = this.$slots.default[0].text;
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

So how do I access the text content inside of the slot?

Borrowing from this answer but rewritten using Options API to access slot text:
computed: {
  translateText() {
      if (this.$slots.default()) {
        return this.getSlotChildrenText(this.$slots.default());
      } else {
        return ''
      }
  }
},
methods: {
  getSlotChildrenText(children) {
    return children.map(node => {
    if (!node.children || typeof node.children === 'string') return node.children || ''
    else if (Array.isArray(node.children)) return this.getSlotChildrenText(node.children)
    else if (node.children.default) return this.getSlotChildrenText(node.children.default())
    }).join('')
  }
}

Using computed this should also be reactive if the slot content updates.
Vue Playground demo

Thanks a lot, it worked! However, if I try to compile with TypeScript, it complains that children and node have type any implicitly. To shut up this error, I just said (children:any) and (node:any). But I still get the error error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
49       if (this.$slots.default()) { How can I fix this??
